# get All records which has all IDs passed in comma separated string in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have two tables: one is **tutor** and another is **TutorSubject**. Now I want to get all those tutors which are having all the subjects passed in comma separated string. For example below is the screenshot of data what i'm getting using below query:

```
Select * from TutorSubject where SubjectId in (92, 1, 2, 91)
```

Output is:

[image]

Now what i want to get is: i want to get all records or all tutors who have all these subjectIds. Means that particular Tutor should have all the subjects passed in string.  As per the above screenshot result. i should get only one tutor whose id is: 31.

Comment: I don't understand.  Tutor 31 is missing subject 106.

Comment: Images of data really isn't helpful to us. Output data is even less helpful when we don't know what the data looked like *before* your question. What does the table `tutor` have to do with your question, when it's not in your SQL?

Comment: @downvoters please comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want tutors with all subjects, you can use `group by` and `having`:

```
Select tutorid
from TutorSubject
where SubjectId in (92, 106, 1, 2, 91)
group by tutorid
having count(*) = 5;  -- 5 is the length of the string
```

If you want to pass this in:

```
with s as (
      select convert(int, value) as subjectid
      from string_split(@s)
     )
select tutorid
from tutorsubject ts join
     s
     on ts.subjectid = s.subjectid
group by tutorid
having count(*) = (select count(*) from s);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get all records or all tutors who have all these subjectIds.

If you want to see all records of `TutorSubject` for which the tutor has the 5 `SubjectId`s, you can do a window count and use it for filtering:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, count(*) over(partition by TutorId) cnt
    from TutorSubject t
    where SubjectId in (1, 2, 91, 92, 106)
) t
where cnt = 5
```

Note: this assumes that `(TutorId, SubjectId)` tuples are unique across table `TutorSubject`.